# How to create a function that returns a function with different arguments?

Tags: r, function, arguments

I'm trying to write a function in R that takes two functions (that are defined with an argument that could be viewed as the same), multiplies them and returns an integral over that product evaluated in some new point. Now, multiplying functions isn't that hard, the problem here lies in the fact that instead of evaluating one of the functions in the argument `x`, I want to evaluate it in `w/x`, where `w` is the new argument (but I only want to do this within the function product). Here is my code:

```
    "%*f%" <- function(a,b) {
        force(a)
        force(b)
        function(x){a(x) * b(x)}
    }

    pdf_product <- function(pdf1, pdf2) {
        pdf3 <- function(x,w) {pdf2(w/x)}

        myfun <- function(x,w) {
            (1/abs(x)) %*f% pdf1(x) %*f% pdf3(x,w)
        }

        function(w) {
           sapply(w, function(w) {
               integrate(function(x) myfun(x,w), llim, ulim)$value
           })
        }
    }

    pdf1 <- function(x) {1/(2-1)} #simple function example1
    pdf2 <- function(x) {1/(6-3)} #simple function example2
    llim <- 1 #lower limit integral
    ulim <- 2 #upper limit integral

    prod <- pdf_product(pdf1, pdf2)
    prod(4) #should evaluate to 0.09589402
```

I know that the last part of `pdf_product` works correctly, given a working function `myfun` (as this is how a single integral over a two-dimensional function is run in R - but correct me if I'm wrong). However, if I run the above code, I get the following error message (with traceback):

```
    Error in integrate(function(x) myfun(x, w), llim, ulim) : 
      evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length 
    5.
    integrate(function(x) myfun(x, w), llim, ulim) 
    4.
    FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
    3.
    lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
    2.
    sapply(w, function(w) {
        integrate(function(x) myfun(x, w), llim, ulim)$value
    }) 
    1.
    prod(4)
```

I have the feeling that this error has something to do with the "change of variable" I introduce by defining `pdf3` from `pdf2`, but I cannot find a way to fix it. I have tried working with the famous R three-dots-principle in the function that `%*f%` returns but that does not work either.

Comment: I'm confused. Your `"%*f%"` composes functions, but in `(1/abs(x)) %*f% pdf1(x) %*f% pdf3(x,w)` you don't pass functions to it. `1/abs(x)` returns a value.

Comment: Ah, I see your point, thanks. But if I change it, the error message changes from the above to `unused argument w`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your problem is that you want to compose two functions, but these functions can have more than two arguments. This might be useful:

```
"%*f%" <- function(a,b, ...) {
  force(a)
  force(b)
  if (length(formals(args(a))) > 1L && 
      length(formals(args(b))) > 1L)
    stop("Only one function with additional parameters allowed.")
  if (length(formals(args(a))) == 1L && 
      length(formals(args(b))) > 1L)
    return(function(x, ...){a(x) * b(x, ...)})
  if (length(formals(args(a))) > 1L && 
      length(formals(args(b))) == 1L)
    return(function(x, ...){a(x, ...) * b(x)})
  if (length(formals(args(a))) == 1L && 
      length(formals(args(b))) == 1L)
    return(function(x){a(x) * b(x)})
  stop("Function without parameters passed")
}

(sign %*f% abs)(-5)
#[1] -5
(sign %*f% `+`)(-5, 1)
#[1] 4
```

Note that if both functions can have more than one parameter, you'd need to design a different way of passing these:

```
"%*f%" <- function(a,b, args1 = NULL, args2 = NULL) {
  stopifnot(is.list(args1) | is.null(args1))
  stopifnot(is.list(args2) | is.null(args2))
  force(a)
  force(b)
  if (length(formals(args(a))) > 1L && 
      length(formals(args(b))) > 1L)
    return(function(x, args1, args2) do.call(a, c(x, args1)) * do.call(b, c(x, args2)))
  #code for the other cases
}

(`^` %*f% `+`)(-5, list(2), list(1))
#[1] -100
```

You would probably better served by looking into using package magrittr if you are a fan of piping.